# Parse Integer.class out of BufferedReader(InputReader) input

Tags: java, string, casting, numbers

*I'd like to write generic code for parsing user input and comparing it to an array of classes, then casting the input accordingly. I.e.:*

1. Object[ ] paramTypes = { String.class, String.class, Integer.class }
2. Object[ ] userInput = { "playerName1", "targetPlayerName", "5" }   *//5 being a String*
3. Each String of the user input is cast to the corresponding classes in paramTypes.
4. Finally, the cast words are put into another Object[ ] castedUserInput for later use.

   ```
   for(int i = 0; i<userInput.length; i++)
     castedUserInput[i] = paramTypes[i].cast(userInput[i]);
   ```

**The problem:**

As soon as paramTypes[i] is Integer.class and the cast is executed, a ClassCastException occurs. The documentation of that exception reads:

*ClassCastException: Thrown to indicate that the code has attempted to cast an object to a subclass of which it is not an instance*

So, neither (Object)"5" (why exactly does that not work?) nor "5" can be cast to subclasses of Number.

Now I understand that Number and String are both subclasses of object but not related to each other apart from that. I'm installing JDK7 to have a look at the sourcecode of *Number* and *ClassCastException*, but I doubt that'll be of much help seeing how I've only been programming for about a year and lack thorough understanding of what the java compilers and virtual machine are doing here exactly.

Could anyone help me out please?

PS: One could of course use a few if clauses and then Integer.parseInt(userInput[i]), Long.parseLong(userInput[i]) etc, but that couldn't be the most efficient solution, right?

Comment: Without calling a parse function, how is the computer to know how to change an arbitrary string in to an integer? From the compilers perspective, it can't tell the difference between "4" and "some random string". (Though clearly you can't cast the latter to an int)

Comment: Casting an object to another type never changes the type of the object. All it does is allowing you to reference the object as another type, if and only if it really has this type. A String is a String, a CharSequence, a Serializable, a COmparable and an Object, but it's not an Integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the class cast exception just as you have described, because the input is of type `String`, and `String` cannot be cast to `Integer`. Instead of casting, you should look into *converting* your input to the expected  parameter types. There are a few frameworks for this purpose, but if you only have a limited number of possible types, you could write something yourself. And `Integer/Long.parseInt` would be one solution.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here, as you correctly note, is that "5" which is a String is being cast to an Integer. Since Integer is not a sub-class of String, the JVM is throwing a ClassCasrException at runtime. Integer and String are both sub-cklsses of Object, hence it is safe to cast String and Integer values to Object (as you are doing when storing strings or integers in an Object array).

One way to fix will be to use:

```
for(int i = 0; i<userInput.length; i++)
  castedUserInput[i] = safeCast(paramTypes[i], userInput[i]);
```

where `safeCast()` does the conversion for you possibly using the if clauses you mention to parse into ints, longs, etc. Another approach, which imho is more generic, will be to use reflection and call the constructor that takes a String argument. Most of the concrete Number classes (Byte, Double, Float, Integer, Long, Short) support such constructors and so you should be good with Number classes. For custom classes you will be required to have a constructor that takes a single String argument. Here is the solution that uses reflection and relies on having a constructor which takes the passed value as an argument:

```
public static Object safeCast(Class paramType, Object value)
        throws NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException,
        InvocationTargetException, InstantiationException {
    if (value == null) {
        return null;
    }
    final Class<?> valueClass = value.getClass();
    if (paramType.isAssignableFrom(valueClass)) {
        return value;
    }
    final Constructor theConstructor = paramType.getConstructor(valueClass);
    return theConstructor.newInstance(value);
}
```